# Не получается запустить тестовое приложение с помощью Cygwin

Tags: node.js, cygwin

Сделал все как написано [тут](http://habrahabr.ru/post/107232/) все прошло успешно кроме запуска server.js Создал его и разместил в директории как описано в источнике. Вот скриншот [link text](http://yande-k88.narod2.ru/files/help.png)

Answer (score 2):

С чего вы решили, что "всё прошло успешно"? Да у вас там каждая команда заканчивается выбросом ошибки: **SyntaxError: invalid syntax.**

К тому же, статья 2010 года. С тех пор node.js давно уже устанавливается без танцев с бубном. Пробовали заходить на сайт [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)? Там прям по центру есть кнопка Install, которая ведет на **node-v0.10.3-x64.msi**. Расширение .msi вам о чем-нибудь говорит?